# C++ Insert into List of Objects

Tags: c++, list, class, visual-c++, insert

can someone tell me how can i add data into my list of class with C++ 
please ?

```
#include <string>
class Person
{
private: 
    std::string Name;
public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
    std::string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    std::string SetName(std::string name)
    {
        name = Name;
        return name;
    }
}; 

void main()
{
    list<Person> lp = new list<Person>();
    Person p = new Person();
    p.Name = "Smith";
    lp.insert(p);
}
```

this is my attempt. Can someone correct me or give me another answer ? Thanks

Comment: Your dynamic allocation isn't needed in this code. Lose *both* `new` invokes.  (And `main` returns, `int`, btw).

Comment: so just like this : 
list<Person> lp;
Person p;
???????

Comment: yes, though you also need `#include <list>` for all of this. Honestly you probably need more than Stack Overflow is going to offer. This isn't *really* a language tutorial site. May I suggest you peruse [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @FalconUA: there is a lot more you could fix in this post...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why isn't your `SetName` only void and needs to return something? If you want to return the new Name, you also should have

```
Name = name;
return Name;
```

You have switched it.

Also, you don't need any of the `new` and *every* main function should return `int` value (usually 0 if no error occurred).

FIXED CODE:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

class Person
{
private: 
    std::string Name;
public:
    //Person();
    //~Person();
    std::string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    void SetName(std::string name)
    {
    Name = name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list<Person> lp;
    Person p;
    p.SetName("Smith");
    lp.push_back(p);
    return 0;
}
```

You need to include lists in order to use them, and you can't assign a private member directly. Also, your declarations are wrong - for this I would recommend some cpp tutorials and reading the documentation.

Comment: thank you for your help ! but the issue is still remaining.
i don't know how to add data into list of class with c++

Answer (score 1):

If by some chance you are using c++11 or greater, consider using:

```
list.emplace_back()
```

or

```
list.emplace_front()
```

which handles construction and insertion. Of course this would be even better if you had a Person constructor that took a string argument.

```
Person::Person(std::string& name) { Name = name; }
```

In which case you could do:

```
lp.emplace_back("Smith");
```

Answer (score 0):

list.insert() takes an iterator, i.e. position at which you want to insert the new element.

You can also do

```
list.push_back(p);
```

This inserts 'p' at the end of the list.

If you do

```
list.push_front(p);
```

insertion happens at the head of list.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, since you're coding in c++ your main function should return an `int`:

  ```
  int main()
  ```
- Second, you're using the `new` keyword on an object that isn't a pointer, correct that:

  ```
  // This would perhaps be better:
  list<Person*> lp;
  Person *p = new Person; // remember to delete p; later
  ```
- I don't see that you have included `<list>` header and using `std`. You need that in order to use list. Or at least write `std::list` or `using std::list;`
- You are trying to assign to a private class member, either declare it public, or use a setter function:

  ```
  p->Name = "Smith"; // remember for pointers, use the '->' or *(p).Name
  ```
- emplace_back() is maybe what you are looking to use (since c++11):

  ```
  lp.emplace_back(p);
  // otherwise, specify an iterator as first argument for insert:
  // lp.insert(lp.end(), p);
  ```